# Solution to the functional equation $f(x^y)=f(x)^{f(y)}$

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation, functional-equations

Consider the functional equation problem
$$ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \text , $$
$$ f \left( a ^ b \right) = f ( a) ^ { f ( b ) } \text , $$
when $ a , b \in \mathbb R $, $ a , b \ge 0 $.

So far the only solution I have is the trivial
$$ f ( x ) = x \text . $$

Does there exist any other possible solution?

Even if the $ f $ doesn't have a closed form in terms of elementary functions, is there some way I could derive a series or an alternative expression for it?

I tried to get a little more creative:
$$ f ( w ) = f \left( w ^ { \frac 1 w } \right) ^ { f ( w ) } \text , $$
which nests deep into
$$ f ( w ) = f \left( w ^ { \frac 1 w } \right) ^ { f \left( w ^ { \frac 1 w } \right) ^ { f \left( w ^ { \frac 1 w } \right) ^ \vdots } } \text , $$
which is equivalent to
$$ \ln \big( f ( w ) \big) = \ln \bigg( f \left( w ^ { \frac 1 w } \right) \bigg) f ( w ) \text . $$
I was hoping to generate some sort of series using this.

Comment: Don't you want the functional equations form $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ to $\mathbb R$? Otherwise the negative values can have any value

Comment: $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ is another trivial answer.

Comment: $f(2)=f(4)=1$ or $f(2)=2$, $f(4)=4$. By looking to $(a,b)=(4,2)$ and $(a,b)=(2,4)$ respectively.

Comment: For any $a>0$ we observe that $f(a) \neq 0$, for then we would have $f(a^a)=f(a)^{f(a)}=0^0$ which is not defined.

Comment: @IndrayudhRoy Many mathematicisn define $0^0=1$. There are strong reasons to do this.

Comment: @wythagoras yea now that I think about that is a better formulation of what I wanted to ask

Comment: @wythagoras Not necessarily. For example we could have $f(2)=3$, $f(4)\approx 2.47805$.

Comment: @MichaelM. But we also want $f(4)=f(2^2)=f(2)^{f(2)}$.

Comment: @wythagoras Oh I see, my mistake. I thought the conclusion only came from $f(2)^{f(4)}=f(4)^{f(2)}$.

Comment: I think this implies that either $f(x)=1$ for all $x>0$ or $f(x)=x$, then. If $f(2)=1$, then $f(2^x)=1$ for all $x$, i.e. $f(x)=1$ for all $x>0$, while $f(0)=1$ or $f(0)=0$ because $f(0^0)=f(1)=1=f(0)^{f(0)}$. But if $f(2)=2$, then $f(x^2)=f(x)^2$ which has solution $f(x)=x^c$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$, and $f(2)=2$ puts $c=1$.

Comment: Your idea leads to something interesting: $f(w)^{\frac{1}{f(w)}}=f((w^{\frac{1}{w}})^w)^{\frac{1}{f(w)}}=f(w)^{f(\frac{1}{w})}$. Following some easy steps, you can get $(f(w)f(\frac{1}{w}))^{f(w)f(\frac{1}{w})}=f(w)f(\frac{1}{w})$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can show that the only *nice* solutions to
$$f\left(x^y\right)=f(x)^{f(y)}\tag0\label0$$
are the identity function, and the constant functions $1$ and $-1$. There are also a few *ugly* solutions.

To avoid problems with $0^0$, let's first find all functions $f$ such that $f:(0,+\infty)\to(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty)$. (Note that because the question is about nonnegative $x$ and $y$ satisfying \eqref{0}, therefore if the domain of $f$ included a negative $x$, then $f(x)$ would be arbitary.)

In the case that $|f(x)|=1$ for every $x>0$, we have $f(x)^{+1}=f(x)^{-1}=f(x)$; so for every $x,y>0$ we get:
$$f\left(x^y\right)=f(x)^{f(y)}=f(x)^{\pm1}=f(x)$$
Thus by fixing $x$ to have a value greater than $1$ and letting $y$ to range over all positive numbers, we conclude that $f$ is constant on $(1,+\infty)$. By the same argument, $f$ is constant on $(0,1)$. So, $f$ must be of the form:
$$\cases{f(x)=a\qquad0<x<1\\f(x)=b\qquad x=1\\f(x)=c\qquad x>1}$$
where $|a|=|b|=|c|=1$. In fact, we can show that every choice of $(a,b,c)$ gives a solution; and the only *nice* ones are the constant functions $1$ and $-1$.

Now, if there is a $z$ such that $|f(z)|\neq1$, then by \eqref{0}:
$$f(z)^{f(xy)}=f\left(z^{xy}\right)=f\big(\left(z^x\right)^y\big)=f\left(z^x\right)^{f(y)}=\left(f(z)^{f(x)}\right)^{f(y)}=f(z)^{f(x)f(y)}$$
$$\therefore f(xy)=f(x)f(y)\tag1\label1$$
$$\therefore f(z)^{f(x+y)}=f\left(z^{x+y}\right)=f\left(z^xz^y\right)=f\left(z^x\right)f\left(z^y\right)=f(z)^{f(x)}f(z)^{f(y)}=f(z)^{f(x)+f(y)}$$
$$\therefore f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\tag2\label2$$
Thus by \eqref{1}, for every $x>0$ we get $f(x)=f\left(\sqrt x\right)^2>0$. So by \eqref{2}, we conclude that $f$ is strictly increasing.
Using \eqref{0}, we get $f(1)=f(1)^{f(1)}$ so $f(1)=1$ which inductively yields $f(r)=r$ for every positive rational number $r$ (by using \eqref{2}). Because $f$ is increasing, it must be the identity function.

Now if we want to find all the functions $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying \eqref{0}, then we should deal with $0^0$ and this expression must be defined. If we define $0^0$ to be something other than $0$ or $1$, then we'll lose the usual algebraic properties of exponentiation. Here, I omit the proof, and just claim that if $0^0=0$ then we'll have these *ugly* solutions:

- $f(x)=0\qquad x\geq0$
- $\cases{f(x)=-1\qquad x=0\\f(x)=1\qquad x>0}$
- $\cases{f(x)=1\qquad x=0\\f(x)=a\qquad x>0}$ where $a=0$ or $a=-1$

and if $0^0=1$ then the only solutions are the *nice* ones.

If we want to include negative numbers in the domain of \eqref{0} (and avoid complex numbers) then $y$ must only take rational values with odd denominator (to avoid problems with defining exponentiation). In this case, we have the *nice* solutions and there may be other solutions.

There are problems with extending the domain and codomain to complex numbers, because exponentiation is a many-valued relation in this case, and also the algebraic properties become complicated. Even it's not clear how to find all the constant solutions! I've asked a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362767/solving-zz-z-in-complex-numbers/1363623#1363623).

Comment: It's interesting that equations (2) and (3) look like the equations for the automorphisms of a field.  But the positive real numbers aren't a field, so I'm not sure if this observation gains us anything.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, its interesting how over the course of months I've come to really appreciate your comment, (mainly because I know now what automorphisms are!). I suppose thats an indicator of slow but steady progress