# Solving $z^z=z$ in Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I wanted to find all complex numbers $z\neq0$ such that $z^z=z$. I observed that $z=\pm1$ satisfies the equation. But I had problems when tried to find all the possible solutions since $z^z$ may take more than one value. I attempted this:
$$z=r(\cos\theta+\mathrm i\sin\theta)$$
$$\therefore\log z=\log r+\mathrm i\theta$$
$$z^{z-1}=1$$
$$\therefore (z-1)\log z=2\pi n\mathrm i\qquad n\in\mathbb Z$$
$$\therefore\cases{(r\cos\theta-1)\log r-r\theta\sin\theta=0\\\theta(r\cos\theta-1)+r\log r\sin\theta=2\pi n}$$
But I couldn't go further. I'm also aware that adding an integer multiple of $2\pi$ to $\theta$ may give another possible value for $\log z$. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Now *that there* is *one damned engaging question*!  ***Endorsed!***

Comment: Often, these types of problems are solved in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Problem is that under the condition that $a$ is not positive real *and* $b$ is not integral, $a^b$ has no unambiguous definition. In particular, when you take $\log$ of both sides to get $z\log z=\log z$, it's not even clear to me that you want the same branch of the logarithm on both sides of the equation.

Comment: After doing some searching with contour plots, I found a couple other *potential* (approximate) solutions: $r \approx .23195$ and $\theta \approx 7.12774$ as well as $r \approx .397315$ and $\theta \approx 9.065525$. You can of course convert $\theta$ to be in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Another seems to be $r\approx .15398$ and $\theta \approx -13.5258$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks for the calculations; but I think $\theta$ can't be converted to be in $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari I meant to get a $z$ in standard polar form, but of course those values of $\theta$ are necessary for the transcendental equation.

Comment: You cant solve the equation arithmetically, just by approximations. I would write to not lose solutions $z=e^{i\varphi + 2k\pi}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I wonder about those solutions, I put them in but do not solve the equation...

Comment: @johannesvalks They solve the original equation. I wanted to avoid the issue with logarithms.

Comment: I have tried that at Wolfram and in those case $z^z \ne z$...

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+%3D+0.23195+exp%28+i+7.12774+%29+and+z%5Ez+-+z

Comment: @johannesvalks Wolfram Alpha is *really* bad at evaluating complex powers. WA and Mathematica do weird things with branch cuts. This is a very well-known issue with the software. You have to write things in polar form to get a better formed problem (for their purposes).

Comment: The first equation is almost zero, but the second yields $-0.253412$ which is not even close to $2 n \pi$...

Comment: @CameronWilliams, what I found is that your solutions are approximations for the real part is zero. The imaginary part does not turn out to be zero at all...

Comment: @johannesvalks I've checked this personally (multiple times) and it works. I'm not sure what it is that's causing the issue for you. It's probably exactly what I said, though. Convert to polar form and check it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The more I think about this question, the more I like it. The key to it is to have a precise idea of what we’re talking about.

We need an unambiguous definition of the natural logarithm, $\log$. It can be defined as a single-valued function only on a simply-connected domain in $\Bbb C$ that omits the origin. Since we know all the positive real solutions of our equation, namely $z=1$, we might as well omit from the plane the whole nonnegative real axis. Then we may specify that $0<\Im(\log z)<2\pi$, so that this logarithm maps onto the open strip between the real axis and a line parallel to it and $2\pi$ units above.

Now, to the equation $z^z=z$ we apply log and get $z\log z=\log z+2k\pi i$, and so $(z-1)\log z=2k\pi i$. This is really infinitely many equations, one for each integer $k$. The value $k=0$ gives us our known value $z=1$, and if you try it for $k=-1$, you can check that since $\log(-1)=\pi i$, there’s your other known solution. It would be fun to see whether there are other solutions for this value of $k$, but I’m going to bet that each other value of $k$ leads to at least one solution.

I’m posting this incomplete answer, and will look for a value with $k=-2$.

Comment: It is not just the logarithm... the expression $z^z$ itself is multivalued by definition.

Comment: Yes, @Masacroso, I’m starting to agree strongly with your position, and thinking that my analysis did not take sufficient account of the multivaluedness of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$
z = z(r,\theta),
$$

so we actually have
$$
z(r,\theta)^{ z(r,\theta) } = z(r,\theta).
$$

Note that
$$
z(r,\theta) = e^{\ln(r) + \mathbf{i} \theta}
= r \cos(\theta) + \mathbf{i} r \sin(\theta),
$$

so we obtain
$$
e^{ \big[ \ln(r) + \mathbf{i} \theta \big]
\big[ r \cos(\theta) + \mathbf{i} r \sin(\theta) \big] }
= e^{\ln(r) + \mathbf{i} \theta},
$$

therefore
$$
\big[ \ln(r) + \mathbf{i} \theta \big]
\big[ r \cos(\theta) + \mathbf{i} r \sin(\theta) \big]
= \ln(r) + \mathbf{i} \big\{ \theta + 2 n \pi \big\}.
$$

So we obtain
$$
\Big[ r \ln(r) \cos(\theta) - r \theta \sin(\theta) - \ln(r) \Big]
+ \mathbf{i} \Big[ r \ln(r) \sin(\theta) + r \theta \cos(\theta)
- \theta - 2 n \pi \Big] = 0.
$$

---

(added to show step)

We get
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rcl}
r \ln(r) \cos(\theta) - r \theta \sin(\theta) &=& \ln(r)\\
r \ln(r) \sin(\theta) + r \theta \cos(\theta) &=& \theta + 2 n \pi
\end{array}
\right.
$$

So
$$
\Big[ r \ln(r) \cos(\theta) - r \theta \sin(\theta) \Big]^2
+ \Big[ r \ln(r) \sin(\theta) + r \theta \cos(\theta) \Big]^2
= \ln^2(r) + \big( \theta + 2 n \pi \big)^2
$$

Thus
$$
r^2 \ln^2(r) + r^2 \theta^2 = \ln^2(r) + \big( \theta + 2 n \pi \big)^2
$$

---

So we obtain

$$
r^2 \ln^2(r) + r^2 \theta^2 = \ln^2(r) + \big( \theta + 2 n \pi \big)^2,
$$

or
$$
\big[ r^2 - 1 \big] \big[ \ln^2(r) + \theta^2 \big]
= \big( \theta + 2 n \pi \big)^2 - \theta^2.
$$

## The case $r=1$

We obtain
$$
\big( \theta + 2 n \pi \big)^2 - \theta^2 = 0,
$$

whence
$$
\theta = - n \pi,
$$

Thus
$$
z = \pm 1
$$

## The case $r \ne 1$

We obtain
$$
\big[ r^2 - 1 \big] \big[ \ln^2(r) + \theta^2 \big]
= 4 n \pi \Big( \theta + n \pi \Big).
$$

But as
$$
z(r,\theta) = z(r,\theta + 2 k \pi),
$$

so the right part can be positive or negative, while the left part does not change sign.
There are no solutions for the case $r \ne 1$.

---

So
$$
z^z=z \Rightarrow z = \pm 1,
$$

as the only solutions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the right part can be positive or negative".  It sounds like you might be trying to solve "all values of $z^z$ are equal to $z$ for every branch cut of $\ln$", which I would call a very strong restriction as it essentially forces $z$ to be real.  My interpretation of the question was that the OP was interested in just one of the multiple values of $z^z$ being equal to $z$.

Comment: Just jumping in *in medias res*, your sixth display seems to be of the form $a+bi=0$, where $a$ and $b$ are real. Doesn’t that mean that both $a$ and $b$ are zero?

Comment: Yes, and when you have these two equation $a=0$ and $b=0$, you can work it out to remove the $\sin()$ and $\cos()$.

Comment: I think @ErickWong's suggestion is spot on here. In the usual branch cut of the complex plane, the solutions you presented are the only ones. However if you do not place restrictions on $\theta$, there are many other solutions.